# Accessing symfony's app_dev.php using homestead vagrant solution

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, homestead, symfony-3.4

I have setup the homestead as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#installation-and-setup) states and performed the following changes to `Homestead.yaml` in order to handle my project:

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/ellakcy_member_app/
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/web
        type: symfony

databases:
    - homestead
name: ellakcy-member-app
hostname: ellakcy-member-app
```

But when I visit over my browser `http://192.168.10.10/` I get the following error:

> You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you look on app_dev.php there is the following snippet of code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

That means that the `app_dev.php` script does not recognize the ip that is being visited therefore in order to prevent any anauthorized access during development it prevents loading the symfony.

In order to bypass this protection you should figure out which is your client's ip on the vagrant virtual network the quick and dirty way is to replace the snippet above with the following snippet of code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    echo 'REMOTE_ADDR: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."<br>";
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

As you can see it prints the correct value that toy should place in the array in:

```
!(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'/*, Found Ip goes there*/], true)
```

In my case it was the `192.168.10.1` one, I guess it shoule be the one in your case too.